# IntelliJ IDEA debugger skips breakpoints when debugging Maven tests

Tags: unit-testing, maven-2, junit, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug Maven tests in IntelliJ IDEA. When I open IDEA's *Maven Projects* view and right-click on **test** goal, I get an option to debug it. Clicking it executes this goal but the execution never stops at any breakpoints. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Running the app externally to IntelliJ (or Eclipse) using: `mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test` then connecting to the running (but waiting) instance, as @milan has suggested (+1) works for me.

Comment: It seems that the Idea debugger has good support over junit project. I created a debug configuration with junit enabled, and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One solution would be to use remote debugging:

1. configure the surefire plugin: `<debugForkedProcess>true</debugForkedProcess>`;
2. run the test (will wait for a remote debugger to connect)
3. create and run a remote debug configuration in IntelliJ (will hit your breakpoint); the port to connect to is 5005.

Comment: Even simpler than changing your config in the pom: Run w/ `-Dmaven.surefire.debug` from the shell.

Comment: Even simpler: `-DforkCount=0`. This will automatically open the debugger without having to run a new debugger configuration in IntelliJ

Answer (score 33):

Just disable the forked mode - something like this in your pom file (under project/build/plugins section):

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.14</version>
<configuration>
    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: `forkMode` is deprecated. Use `<forkCount>0</forkCount>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running unit tests with maven failsafe rather than surefire, then debugger will not stop and you have to manually run a failsafe debugger command line and then intellij will be able to stop on the breakpoints.  I am unsure if using `<forkMode>never</forkMode>` option on failsafe solves this issue.

As I describe here:  https://github.com/djangofan/maven-failsafe-debug-example

Answer (score 0):

Your sources for the dependencies do not match the binary code. Make sure you're using the same sources.

Comment: No... unfortunately it's not that simple. It's about the separate process Maven runs test in. If you prevent forking, the debugger will stop, but for some reason it stops always, even if I tried to run and not to debug.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, setting environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS=-DforkCount=0` worked. In linux, you can do this on the command line:

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-DforkCount=0 MAVEN_DEBUG_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8000 mvnDebug test
```