# Application not stopping at set breakpoint using mvnDebug

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDE for a spring boot application. For many reasons I prefer to use external terminal to run the application rather then using the inbuilt run and debug option in the IDE itself.

I run the application with the command `mvn spring-boot:run` on an external terminal. It works as expected but I am not able to debug the application. I am using the command `mvnDebug spring-boot:run` on the external terminal when I want to debug as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853683/2623749). Then I create a `Remote` configuration to connect at port `8000` which it successfully does. But the application doesn't stop at the breakpoints which I am setting.

I am sure that Intellij is able to connect to the `mvnDebug` process because as soon as I press `Debug` button in IDE I get the following output.

> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8000', transport:
>   'socket'

Also, I know that the IDE is able to make changes in the classpath because as soon as I make changes in `.java` files, the spring boot server restarts in the external terminal with the latest changes.

But still the application doesn't stop at the set breakpoints. What else do I need to do?

**Other info**:
I am using Java 8, Maven 3.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mvnDebug` will open for debug the JVM that runs maven.

The plugin by default is configured in a way that it spawns another JVM to run the Java Spring Boot Application  (a forked process).

So you're probably connecting to the Maven's VM.

So you should specify debug parameters in Spring Boot maven plugin configurations:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <configuration>
          <jvmArguments>
            -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
          </jvmArguments>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The source is [spring boot plugin official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html)

Comment: It worked! Any idea where I can read about the options "sever=y,suspend=y"?

Comment: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/what_are_the_options_of