# Java 17 debugger not stopping to breakpoints

Tags: java, maven, debugging

I created a project using `Java 17` and i'm trying to enter debug trough the running command `spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.fork=false`, but debugger won't stop at the breakpoints. It only starts when i run the project from the `Application.java` class. I've already tried to follow the steps in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853683/22629324) but it doesn't work.

I tried to uninstall and re-install `IntelliJ`, tried to delete the `.idea` folder inside the project, tried to install `Java 17`  and `Maven 3.9.2` and set them as environment variables, but nothing worked.

I tried also to execute the debugger in another project that use the same Maven version but `Java 1.8` and it works normally