# debuging a unit test in maven is not stopping at breakpoint

Tags: maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea, groovy

I am trying to debug a failing unit test, when I put run debug, the test runs and continues until it ends all the tests without stopping at any breakpoint, is that normal ?

Comment: Try using JUnit debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA instead of Maven. When you debug Maven goal, debugger connects to the Maven JVM, while your actual test code may run in the forked JVM which has no debugging enabled, therefore breakpoints do not work (debugger is connected to a different JVM which doesn't have your code running).

Comment: the problem is when I am running junit I am getting an error, so is there a way to debug from mvn?!

Comment: You can use remote debug. Configure your Maven test runner to start forked JVM in debug mode, then connect to this JVM from IntelliJ IDEA Remote debug configuration.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573289/intellij-idea-debugger-skips-breakpoints-when-debugging-maven-tests helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In IntelliJ, how do i debug a maven test goal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784781/in-intellij-how-do-i-debug-a-maven-test-goal)

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked in IDEA. You need to add `-DforkCount=0` JVM argument in your IDE. That is, because tests normally run on a separate JVM. Source: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html